# Is it possible to bind two variables in xml?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Here **point_of_sale_list_item.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>    
       <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Merchant" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here root adapter:

```
public abstract class PreviewSortAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter {

    public PreviewSortAdapter(Context context, @Nullable OrderedRealmCollection data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        super(data, true);
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, viewType, parent, false);
        setClickHandler(binding);
        return new PreviewBaseViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object obj = getItem(position);
        PreviewBaseViewHolder previewViewHolder = (PreviewBaseViewHolder) holder;
        ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = previewViewHolder.getBinding();
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.item, obj);
        viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(); //binding must be executed immediately
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getLayoutForPosition(position);
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutForPosition(int position);

    private class PreviewBaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ViewDataBinding binding;

        private PreviewBaseViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        private ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }
    }

}
```

I use method `setVariable()` to bind variable "**item**" with model.

And here concrete child adapter:

```
public class MapListSortAdapter extends PreviewSortAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = MapListSortAdapter.class.getName();

    public MapListSortAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<Merchant> data) {
        super(context, data, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutForPosition(int position) {
        return R.layout.point_of_sale_list_item;
    }

}
```

In this I adapter I specify only layout xml: **point_of_sale_list_item**

OK. All work fine.

But now I need to read set phone number from another model.
In xml in id `android:id=@+id/phoneTextView`

So I need to bind **second** variable. 
Something like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>    
       <variable
           name="item"
           type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Merchant" />

       <variable
            name="point"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.PointOfSale" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@{point.phone}"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here pojo code:

```
public class PointOfSale {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

But of course I get error, because second vairable (**point**) was not bind:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.PointOfSale.phone
file:\myProject\app\src\main\res\layout\point_of_sale_list_item.xml
loc:61:28 - 61:38
****\ data binding error ****
```

So :

1. Is it possible to bind second varaible?
2. How I can get data from second variable?

Or maybe create new model that concatenate this 2 models?

Answer (score 4):

I've definitely done that.  In my case:

```
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.todtenkopf.myfrontpage.viewmodel.favoriteteam.FavoriteTeamVM"/>
    <variable name="matchup" type="com.todtenkopf.myfrontpage.viewmodel.favoriteteam.FavoriteTeamVM.Matchup"/>
```

You don't show the code for `PointOfSale`. Is `phone` a public field or do you have a `getPhone` accessor?  Is sounds more like the problem is along those lines.

Comment: You argue that if that in `PointOfSale` has setter/getter methods, then I can use 2 variables in xml?

Comment: no, I'm saying that I think it's possible the problem has nothing to do with 2 variables.  I have used 2 variables with no problem.  I was conjecturing that the error you were seeing might be because `phone` is not a public field or because you don't have a public `getPhone` getter.  Perhaps you can post the `PointOfSale` code?

Comment: please try making `phone` public.  Or better, add an accessor `getPhone`.  It can't bind to `phone` because it is private.  It has nothing to do with 2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <data>   
      <variable
                name="object name"
                type="your pojo classpath" />

      <variable
                name="handlers"
                type="your handler class path " /> 
    </data>
```

working example, link shared below
*https://www.androidhive.info/android-working-with-databinding/*